# step and impulse function in simulink

Tags: matlab, simulink

How can I fix this error?

```
K = [ 1 2 3 ];

for i = 1 : N
    numerator = [ K(i) 0 ];
    denominator = [ 1 ];
    sys = tf(numerator, denominator);

    step(sys, t);

    impulse(sys, t);
end
```

Error using DynamicSystem/step (line 95)
Cannot simulate the time response of improper (non-causal) models.

I must to do perfect differential  in simulink function -> G(s) = K*s

Answer (score 0):

From your text, I guess, that you might have mixed-up the numerator and denominator. (If you didn't, MATLAB does not simulate improper models where above the fraction line are a higher degree of s than below;) ). If you wanted to simulate G(s) = K*s, they were mixed:

```
K = [ 1 2 3 ];
t = 0:0.1:1;

for i = 1:length(K)
    numerator = 1;
    denominator = [K(i) 0];
    sys = tf(numerator, denominator);

    step(sys, t);
    hold on
end
```

[image: step response drawing]